# Multiple checkboxes based on the dates available in my calendar

Tags: php

I have a simple piece of code that will enable me to echo a start and end date in a particular month, what I am trying to do is create a registration system.

I have the dates in a table as table headers, and then in the first column I have member name. What I want to achieve is a check-box or radio element for each day but I'm struggling to implement this I'm not getting the results expected instead I am getting back this:

`2013-10-01 13:44:213Europe/Berlin 2013-10-01 13:44:213Europe/Berlin`

From this:

```
 <?php  
 $dt = "<td><input type='checkbox' name='student[davidsmith]' value='Y' checked /></td>";
 foreach($startDate as $dt){
 echo "$dt";
} ?>
```

I feel like I'm most likely missing the point and the method to do this. Perhaps there is a cleaner more simpler method to achieve what I am looking to achieve. (currently I have no database interactions I am really trying to get the framework sorted initially).

If anyone could help me complete this that would be great!

date.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Attendance Example</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action='this_page.php' method='post'>
<table>
<th>Member</th>
<?php 
$startDate = new DateTime();
$endDate = new DateTime('2013-09-31');

for ($c = $startDate; $c <= $endDate; $c->modify('+1 day')) {
       echo "<th>".$c->format('d')."</th>"; }
 ?>
<tr>
    <td>Memeber One</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='student[davidsmith]' value='Y' /></td>
     <?php  
     $dt = "<td><input type='checkbox' name='student[davidsmith]' value='Y' checked /></td>";
     foreach($startDate as $dt){
     echo "$dt";
   } ?>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Member Two</td>
 <?php  
     $dt = "<td><input type='checkbox' name='student[davidsmith]' value='Y' checked /></td>";
     foreach($c as $dt){
     echo "$dt";
   } ?>            <td><input type='checkbox' name='student[davidsmith]' value='1' /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Comments on your code :**

you are getting the result you posted because :

1. `$startDate` in `foreach($startDate as $dt)` is not an array therefore there no loop
2. when you say as `$dt` you are overiding the $dt variable therfore `$dt = "<td><input type='checkbox' name='student[davidsmith]' value='Y' checked /></td>";` acts as if it never existed

**My Solution :**

 now if I understood you correctly I believe this is the code you are looking for

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Attendance Example</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action='this_page.php' method='post'>
<table>
<th>Member</th>
<?php 
$startDate = new DateTime();
$endDate = new DateTime('2013-09-31');
$days = array();

for ($c = $startDate; $c <= $endDate; $c->modify('+1 day')) {
       echo "<th>".$c->format('d')."</th>";array_push($days,$c); }
 ?>
<tr>
    <td>Memeber One</td>

     <?php  

     foreach($days as $dt){
     echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="student[davidsmith]" value="'.$dt->format('d') .'" /></td>';
   } ?>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Member Two</td>
 <?php  
      foreach($days as $dt){
     echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="student[davidsmith]" value="'.$dt->format('d') .'" /></td>';
   } ?>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

first we put the days in an array then we loop on them and create check boxes for each day . each checkbox should have value corresponding to the day it represents . hope this is what you are looking for .